# SFTP Upload using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, expect

I have a  Script program which uses Bash with Expect.
This shell script is doing a SFTP Upload.

Here is the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

/usr/bin/expect << EOD
spawn sftp $loginid@server
#expect "*Are you sure you want to continue connecting*"  {send "yes\r" }
expect "Password:*"
send $pwd\r
expect "sftp> "
send "lcd $locdirectory\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "cd $remDirect\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "put $file\r"
expect "sftp> "
send "bye\r"
expect EOD
```

while running this script it is going to infinite loop after bye statement.

It keeps printing 'Y' on the terminal and never ends.

Please suggest why is it happening.

Comment: Have you considered using a client designed, documented and supported for automated use, such as `lftp`? (Yes, it supports sftp). Using `expect` to script a program not meant to be automated has a much higher risk of future versions changing in ways that break your script.

Comment: Also, this is **only** using expect, not bash at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- `expect << EOD` is shell syntax. :)

Comment: @whjm, but the shebang causes it to be run with expect, not with a shell as interpreter at all, making that shell syntax just an error if it's executed with `./scriptname`. If it's going to have wrapper content requiring a shell, the shebang needs to actually invoke one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- The OP must be running the script with `bash scriptname` instead of `./scriptname` I guess.

Comment: @whjm, ...in which case they're not seeing that bug right now, but it's still very much a bug. And under the circumstances, that invocation is needless -- if they took out the wrapper bits and ran `./scriptname` instead, their invocation would be marginally faster (directly invoking `expect`) and they wouldn't need the useless shell bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work with this issue.  I had to uncomment below line from the script.

```
#expect "*Are you sure you want to continue connecting*"  {send "yes\r" }
```

My server was not having the key of destination server , So instead of prompting for password it was prompting for 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting' ? and there was nothing proper being passed in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `#!/usr/bin/expect` then you don't have a bash script: remove the line

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
```

and then take @whjm's advice

Also, the way to *conditionally* expect "continue?" is

```
expect {
    "*Are you sure you want to continue connecting*"  {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "Password:*" {send $pwd\r}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. i do have very limited knowledge on scripting. Thanks for your suggestion.